# How to make an alert with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a .NET application with several text boxes. If the form is not complete when the user presses the submit button, I need a box (an "alert" I think) to pop up that says something like "This form must be completed by the employee". After closing the pop up it needs to redirect to the next form. I think this should be pretty simple, but I know very little about javascript and client-side functions. Or is there a way I could write this on server-side? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get a chance to try ASP.Net Validation Controls with Validation Summary?

Comment: Do you mean requiredfieldvalidators and things like that? To be more clear, the textbox is not a required field, but the person completing the form (someone from HR) just needs to be notified that if they don't complete it, the employee (a new hire) they are completing it for needs to complete the form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

But you better use the available validatos already presents in Asp.Net:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_validators.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could just put a if statement in your javascript function.

```
alert("This form must be completed by the employee");
//automatic link to new page
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the html code you will have the button:

```
 <body>
   <input type="button" Value="Click Me" onclick="myAlertFunction()" />
 </body>
```

in the `<head></head>` you will write a script like this:

```
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="javascript/text">
     function myAlertFunction()
     {
        alert("This form must be completed by the employee");
     }
  </script>
</head>
```

Good luck!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate data in form in client-side , you can use javascript to get value in each text box and do some validation. If some wrong you can use alert function to send some message to use like,

```
alert("This form must be completed by the employee");
```

If you is not familiar with JS , want to do validation in server-side. You can send alert to client by below C# code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ALERT","message to alert", true);
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? What I thought would work ended up not working. I got the message even when the box had a value. Where would I insert that code?

Answer (score 0):

Java script function

```
function ShowError() {
      alert("Please enter all the fields");
      return false;
  }
```

In Code behind(C#)  call the function

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "ShowError();", true);
```